# Crash when updating adapter in listview

Tags: android, listview

Im using a [Sectioned adapter](http://code.google.com/p/prx-android/source/browse/trunk/prp-android/src/org/prx/prp/view/SectionedAdapter.java). Each section has a "subAdapter".

I get a problem when im removing all sections, and adding new ones. If the new amount of Sections > old amount of sections.

```
10-27 08:08:33.789: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21550): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
10-27 08:08:33.789: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21550):     at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:5283)
10-27 08:08:33.789: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21550):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4092)
10-27 08:08:33.789: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21550):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2523)
10-27 08:08:33.789: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21550):     at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3733)
10-27 08:08:33.789: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21550):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
10-27 08:08:33.789: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21550):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
10-27 08:08:33.789: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21550):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
10-27 08:08:33.789: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21550):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
10-27 08:08:33.789: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21550):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
```

From what I've read this is a problem with getViewTypeCount. Im guessing that the method isn't called when Im updating the adapter and calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

The problem doesn't occur if i set a new instance of the adapter as listAdapter.

How can I solve this problem? Can I force the activity to recall getViewTypeCount ?

Comment: Please add the code from your adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Im guessing that the method isn't called when Im updating the adapter and calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Correct. `getViewTypeCount()` is only called once.

> How can I solve this problem?

Do not change the value of `getViewTypeCount()` for the lifetime of your adapter.

> Can I force the activity to recall getViewTypeCount ?

Not that I am aware of, sorry.

Comment: From the javadoc `This method will only be called when the adapter is set on the AdapterView`

Answer (score 0):

**Hack Alert**

If you are using Etsy's `StaggerredGridView` (and copy the code in as a module), or use something that `extends AbsListView` you can get it to recall `getViewTypeCount()` whenever you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Here is the original code (for `StaggeredGridView` - `ExtendableListView.java`:

```
@Override
public void setAdapter(final ListAdapter adapter) {
    // ... other code

    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mObserver);
        mRecycleBin.setViewTypeCount(mAdapter.getViewTypeCount());
    }

    requestLayout();
}
```

As you can see `mAdapter.getViewTypeCount()` is only called when you call setAdapter.
So if we copy this code and move it to the place `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called we can update our adapter with new types!

Which is here (for `StaggeredGridView` - `ExtendableListView.java`:

```
    class AdapterDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {

        private Parcelable mInstanceState = null;

        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            // other code

            mRecycleBin.clearTransientStateViews();
            mRecycleBin.setViewTypeCount(mAdapter.getViewTypeCount()); // ADD THIS

            // other code
            requestLayout();
        }

        // more methods
     }
```

I have no idea if this effects performance or recycling, by reading this you take all blame for the above code.
    :-)